# Numerical integration of oscillatory function

Tags: numerical-integration

I am trying to evaluate the following oscillatory integration numerically but the answers are wrong or not accurate enough. I don't know what the problem is.

```
B = 2.5*10^(-6); l = 0.02; V = 0.01;
X[t_] := -((4 l t)/(B V)) - (4 I l (Exp[-V t] - 1))/(V (Exp[I B V] - 1))
k[w_] := Re[NIntegrate[Exp[I w t] Exp[X[t]], {t, 0, \[Infinity]}]]
```

I know from theoretical calculation that $k(w)/k(-w) =\exp(B w)$ but as you see below it is not true for the *Mathematica* answers for large $w$.

```
{k[2*10^6]/k[-2*10^6], Exp[B 2*10^6]}
```

> ```
> {2.05121, 148.413}
> ```

I have tried changing the `Accuracygoal` and `WorkingPrecision` but it didn't help.

Comment: With more precision, I can't make Mathematica think the answer is anything other than `9.571…`. (Changing all the inexact numbers to exact numbers means Mathematica is free to use greater precision than machine precision.)

Comment: And with $w=3$ I obtain $k(w)/k(-w)$ being very close to 1, not $e^5$.

Comment: Are you sure that $\exp(Bw)$ is the theoretical convergence for large $w$ rather than small $w$?

Comment: For higher precision and accuracy goals computations it is better to use definitions with exact numbers. I.e. `B = 25/10 * 10^6; l = 2/100; V=1/100` .

Answer (score 3):

The integral can be solved exactly:

```
k[w_] = Integrate[Exp[I w t] Exp[X[t]], {t, 0, ∞}]
(*
  ConditionalExpression[(
   4^((-4 l + I B V w)/(B V^2)) * E^((4 I l)/((-1 + E^(I B V)) V)) *
   ((I l)/((-1 + E^(I B V)) V))^((-4 l + I B V w)/(B V^2)) *
   (Gamma[(4 l - I B V w)/(B V^2)] -
    Gamma[(4 l - I B V w)/(B V^2), (4 I l)/((-1 + E^(I B V)) V)])
    )/V, 
   Re[V] > 0]
*)
```

The plot seems to agree with [bbgodfrey's](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/1063/bbgodfrey):

```
Block[{B = 25*10^(-7), l = 2/100, V = 1/100},
  Table[N[{w, k[w]/k[-w]}, 3],
   {w, 1, 10000000, 100000}]
  ] // ListLinePlot
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by Patrick Stevens, it is highly desirable to use exact numbers.

```
B = 25*10^(-7); l = 2/100; V = 1/100;
```

Further, `X[t]`is entirely negligible for `t > 1/10`.

```
LogPlot[Evaluate[ReIm[Exp[X[t]]]], {t, 0, 1/10}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

allowing the upper limit on the integral to be set to `1/10`, which reduces running time.

```
k[w_] := Re[NIntegrate[Exp[I w t] Exp[X[t]], {t, 0, 1/10}, WorkingPrecision -> 30]]
```

High `WorkingPrecision` is essential to obtain reasonable accuracy at large `w`. The ratio, `k[w]/k[-w]`,  then can be computed at reasonable speed over a wide range of `w`.

```
Quiet@Plot[k[w]/k[-w], {w, 0, 10000000}]
```

[image]

**Addendum**

In response to a question by Patrick Stevens abount truncating the range of integration, I point out that `Re[X[t]]`, the exponential of which is the magnitude of the integrand, is given by

```
FullSimplify[Re[X[t]] // ComplexExpand, t > 0]
(* E^(4 (-800000 t + E^(-t/100) (-1 + E^(t/100)) Cot[1/80000000])) *)
```

which is strictly negative and decreases linearly for large `t`.

```
Plot[Evaluate[ReIm[X[t]]], {t, 0, 200}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Thus, the integrand decreases exponentially for large `t`.  That the truncation also makes sense at small `t` can be shown by truncating the integral at `1` instead of `1/10`.  The computation, although somewhat slower, gives results that are indistinguishable to the eye.

Comment: I'm afraid of "is entirely negligible" when you're truncating infinite regions - $1/n$ is entirely negligible for $n > 10^{100}$, and yet the integral of $1/x$ is still divergent…

Comment: @PatrickStevens  Perhaps, I should  point out in the answer that it is decreasing exponentially at large `t` and already is down to 10^-300 at `t = 0.2`..

Comment: The exponential decrease is enough for me, but I'd prefer that to be proved or at least indicated :P

Comment: @PatrickStevens  Done